# Slack notification on Jira notifications, for me only

Tags: jira, slack

Is it possible to set up Slack so that I get a notification when I receive a Jira notification?

I am looking for a way to do this for myself only. I don't want to send notifications to a Slack channel visible to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Jira Cloud app has options for this: https://my.slack.com/apps/A2RPP3NFR-jira-cloud!

There's more info in the Atlassian page as well: https://www.atlassian.com/partnerships/slack?tab=jira